# Derive a finite difference approximation to this BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose the BVP is

$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} - y = f(x),$  for all $0 < x < l, $

where $y(0) = 0$ and $y(l) = 1$.

How to prove why the GE is $O(h2)$?

And how to derive a finite difference approximation to the above BVP such that its global error (GE) is $O(h2)$?

Thanks for answering

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $h$ in your first statement about the global error? What order 2 discretizations of the second derivative do you know?